# Return Value from API to Cordova (Via File Transfer)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cordova, file-transfer

Hi I'm trying to return a value from a API call via the file transfer plugin  for cordova. I've shown below my php code for the API which is working fine and the Cordova code. Essentially what I want to do is turn the return statement in the API into a JS variable in Cordova.
This is the Php code, the move_uploaded_file part works fine:

```
    protected function uploadPicturesAction()
    {
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "/home/sean/images/{$name}.jpg");
    return $name;
    }
```

This is the cordova part, so here I am trying to get the variable $name to become a JS variable.

```
    fileTransfer.upload(image, encodeURI("sean.co.uk/api.php?action=uploadPictures"), imagePage2(), fail, options);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a PHP file (e.g. `loadpics.php`) that contains the function `uploadPicturesAction` either through including a library file or just hard coded.
2. To that file add as last line: `echo uploadPicturesAction();`
3. In your javascript use ajax to call `loadpics.php` and assign the return value to your javascrpt variable.